# When is it better to pull all data and filter, or pull the data filtered

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working with Spark (pyspark) and MongoDB as a relational database.

We are running into some performance issues and the answers I found here were not directly related to Big Data.

We pull our entire mongoDB and then filter in Spark and when we apply some filters, some of the columns we don't filter are still present in the spark DataFrame(let me explain better this last case later).

My questions, besides a general understanding of the question's tittle:

1. Pull and filter, or filter and pull. If it's not a clear answer what are the parameters to start taking into account?
2. Let's say I have a Spark DataFrame with columns A,B,C and I filter only on C, it would be better (assuming I pulled everything) to drop then A and B?

Any links or readings regarding this are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - pull filtered data , it is more efficient to pull only the data you want. most database are optimize to do filter operation. the perfect case is when you can partition your data on your filtering columns (in your case columns C i guess)

2 - I am not sure but i think it's better to drop the colums you dont use, mainly to reduce the shuffle size if shuffle you have. and it also make your DataFrame more clear

Comment: Thanks for your answer, for point 1 I was just wondering that maybe at some given point the database optimization are too slow and some tools such Spark are faster handling the entire table rather than filtering from database, or if there was something like a data threshold where one operation is better than the another.